# Equivalents of rikaichan for Mongolian

Tags: resource-request, mongolian, software

I've read that [Rikaichan](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/757/91) (and its equivalents) allow you to hover your mouse over a word and see its phonetic reading and translation.

What tools like that (just the translation, not the phonetic reading), if any, are available for Mongolian written in Cyrillic?

Comment: Have you checked for existing online dictionaries? Any solution will need to use one, so it might be a good place to start. Jim Breen's [Edict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDICT) dictionary existed long before Rikaichan, though Rikaichan is a great implementation for using it on-the-fly.

Comment: Don't be disheartened to learn that Mongolian spelling is not phonetic. For instance the word "шинэ" meaning "new" is pronounced like "shin" and not like "shin-eh". It is more phonetic than English or traditional Mongolian script though.